# python ImportError: No module named resource in fanstatic configure.zcml in grok-based project

Tags: python, zope, importerror, grok, zcml

```
  File "/root/.buildout/eggs/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
zope.configuration.xmlconfig.ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/srv/csw/parts/etc/site.zcml", line 4.2-4.27
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/../src/../configure.zcml", line 4.2-4.37
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/root/.buildout/eggs/grokui.admin-0.9-py2.7.egg/grokui/admin/configure.zcml", line 4.2-4.35
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/root/.buildout/eggs/grokui.base-0.5.1-py2.7.egg/grokui/base/configure.zcml", line 7.2-7.38
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/root/.buildout/eggs/zope.fanstatic-0.9.1-py2.7.egg/zope/fanstatic/configure.zcml", line 9.2-9.27
    ImportError: No module named resource
```

previously all was working fine. I made a few code changes, uploaded to server and started up my python paster instance to test. But the above stack trace occurred on startup and I haven't changed *anything* in setup.py or other config files for resource.py (essentially a cfg file telling the fanstatic package where static web resources such as images are) to suddenly disappear from the runtime. I have checked & double checked the source, resource.py and all other python files are where they should be.

I've ran buildout again to ensure something wasn't deleted accidentally but still getting the same error above.

Any idea why fanstatic would stop finding resource.py in a grok-based project?

Comment: Have you tried rolling back to the previous deployment point? E.g. undo all your changes and see if the site runs again?

Comment: yes tried this and still giving same error. No one else has touched the server.

Comment: update - found it. My upload script added an extra __init__.py to a directory that was not a python module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My upload script added an `__init__.py` to the top-level package directory thus grok was looking in this directory and not the appropriate module subdirectory for `resource.py`.